# Dealing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to checkingAccount.BankEntry

Tags: java

Dealing with a ClassCastException, and haven't found an answer.

Am I supposed to parse elements using the ArraList, and then convert elements to StringsList?

I would appreciate some help in solving this issue.

This is my code that is causing the issue, but I don't know how to fix it:

I have these methods in the doGet method of my servlet.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);


    List<BankAccountEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BankAccountEntry>();

    // Pre-populate the guestbook with a few entries
    entries.add(new BankAccountEntry("efd", "df", 100.00, 24.40));

    entries.add(new BankAccountEntry("dfd", "dfd", 45.00, 25.50));

    entries.add(new BankAccountEntry("ssd", "dfd", 50.00, 65.50));


    getServletContext().setAttribute("entries", entries);
}




List<BankAccountEntry> entries = (List<BankAccountEntry>)     context.getAttribute("entries");






 String query = request.getParameter("query"); 




    This past causes the error, but not sure why:
        if (query == null ||  ((BankAccountEntry) entries).getDescription().contains( query.trim() ) || ((BankAccountEntry) entries).getName().contains( query.trim() ) ) {
            // Send the User back to the Guest Book page
        }

        String search = request.getParameter("query");

        if (query == null ||  ((BankAccountEntry)    entries).getDescription().contains( query.trim() ) || ((BankAccountEntry)     entries).getName().contains( query.trim() ) ) {
            // Send the User back to the Guest Book page
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code

```
List<BankAccountEntry> entries
```

entries is a List, but here

```
((BankAccountEntry) entries)
```

your are trying to cast it to a singular `BankAccountEntry`

Maybe in this code you should be iterating over the list?

if you want to iterate

```
for (BankAccountEntry bae : entries) {

   if (bae.getDescription().contains(query.trim()) {
      // whatever
   }
}
```

Comment: I understood that part of the various solutions here, but I am not sure how to implement it.  Can you help me implement please? Eclipse recommended that casting. Why is it wrong, if it what Eclipse recommended?

Comment: In you code you add 3 entries to the list, so when you are doing `getDescription` which entry do you want to compare it to?  All of them?  I have edited my answer to show how to iterate

Comment: Wombat, yes, I want to compare to all of them as I am doing a SEARCH Function using a servlet and a search form.

Comment: Holy smokes! I didn't recognize my error. Thank you.

Comment: Generally, don't trust Eclipse when it suggests to cast something, since Eclipse doesn't understand what you are doing. Only do that if you would have done it manually anyway.

Comment: @Roland, yeah, I see that now. That really threw me off. Thank you.